# Macro to add formulas where the are multiple rows above

Tags: excel, vba

I've been doing the company financial summaries, I've been doing a lot of the leg work manually (sorting by product, company, etc.). The problem is I've been using the below macro to add in two rows, so I can work out spends per customer.

Now what I want to do is add in those breaks, but in the first blank row, I want to copy and paste the values from the cells above for columns `A`, `B` and `C`. In column D and `E` I would like to sum the contiguous cells above, while column F should work out the difference between the calculated values in `D` & `E` (so `=D-E`), while column `G` should work out the `% (=(Fx/Dx)*100)`. If there is a way to do this only if there is more than one row above all the better.

The code that I've been using so far is below, which gives me the line breaks I've been using. But with my RSI, copying the requisite cells and doing all the formulas manually isn't helping.

```
Sub AddBlankRows()
'
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim oRng As Range

Set oRng = Range("b1")

iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column

Do
'
If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
    Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=x1Down
    Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=x1Down
    iRow = iRow + 3
Else
    iRow = iRow + 1
End If
'
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""
'
End Sub
```

#### Example data

[image: Original Data]

#### What I'm aiming for

[image: What I'm aiming for]

I'm a complete novice in this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some sample data?

Comment: I can, but I'm not sure how to paste in the correct format into the comments though.

Comment: You can [edit it into your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55949876/edit)

Comment: @jsheeran thank you, image added into the original description.

Comment: I am not trying to answer your question here. If you expect to do this kind of work more, then I would recommend you to give python and pandas a try. Here's a play list which may be get you started. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_QXMwezPJE&list=PL5-da3qGB5ICCsgW1MxlZ0Hq8LL5U3u9y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative solution you might want to consider is to keep the data in its original format and add a total row. If the data is a table, you can do this by selecting **Total Row** from the **Design** tab; otherwise, you can use the `SUBTOTAL()` formula and auto-filtering to achieve the same result. I've used tables for my example.

Without filtering, you get the results for the whole data set:

[image]

When you filter on a particular value of `Account` or `Customer`, it instead summarises the values for those rows only:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, I accidentally clicked on the Data tab and noticed the sub-total function which also does something similar and a bit closer to the final output I needed for the summary printout.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, StartRow As Long, EndRow As Long
    Dim CurrentAccount As String, PreviousAccount As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        StartRow = LastRow + 1

        For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1

            CurrentAccount = .Range("B" & StartRow).Value
            PreviousAccount = .Range("B" & i).Value

            If CurrentAccount <> PreviousAccount Then

                EndRow = i

                .Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

                StartRow = i

            End If

        Next i

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        StartRow = 0
        EndRow = 0

        For i = 2 To LastRow

            If .Range("B" & i).Value <> "" And StartRow = 0 And EndRow = 0 Then
                StartRow = i
            ElseIf .Range("B" & i).Value = "" And StartRow <> 0 And EndRow = 0 Then
                EndRow = i - 1
            End If

            If StartRow <> 0 And EndRow <> 0 Then

                .Range("D" & i).Formula = "=SUM(D" & StartRow & ":D" & EndRow & ")"
                .Range("E" & i).Formula = "=SUM(E" & StartRow & ":E" & EndRow & ")"
                .Range("F" & i).Formula = "=D" & EndRow & "-" & "E" & EndRow
                .Range("G" & i).Formula = "=(E" & EndRow & "/" & "D" & EndRow & ")" & "*" & 100

                StartRow = 0
                EndRow = 0

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```